# Would 16KB clusters be better than 4KB for 1TB NTFS partition on a very slow PC?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-xp, partitioning

I'm running a desktop PC with legacy Windows XP. The operating system is on an SSD drive. Data is stored on a 3.5 inch 750GB internal hard drive.

The 750GB hard drive is making noises, so I will replace it. I have a spare 1TB drive and also a 2TB drive.

I want two equal partitions although I am not sure if I need to use both hard drives. Old guidelines say to format using 4K clusters ("allocation unit").

However that was suggested in times when storage was more expensive.  As the PC is slow, I figured a 16K cluster size might be lighter on the CPU for various disk operations. I reckon 16K wouldn't waste a significant amount of space as files are larger these days.

MY QUESTIONS ARE; Is 16K a sensible way to go? Should both partitions go on the 1TB drive or the 2TB drive? Any other thoughts?

---

DATA REQUIREMENT:

I will use a 1TB partition to store mainly documents (approx 2MB) and books (usually 5MB to 50MB) and a few audio files (say 10 to 20MB).

Also I will have a separate 1TB "porn" partition (very large number of 0.25 to 3MB jpegs, plus some 50 to 300 MB vids)

WINDOWS XP PC:

A tower PC from 2004. Cpu is AMD Athlon 64 with 4GB DDR2 memory, and SATA drives. Running Windows XP Works well enough for my documents and web browsing.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: XP is very insecure. Also if your computer malfunctions at some point, there is no way to rebuild XP properly any more. Time to move on.

Comment: Indeed ^^^ . Try Windows 10 that should work fine even in that ancient hardware. If not then use any lightweight Linux distro - AntiX is strongly recommended for old hardware -.. Anything but an obsolete and unsafe OS, especially XP that only takes secionds online to be pwned.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser. We're a Question and Answer site and so things are a little different around here than a general forum. The Help section is a good place to start to understand how and why. To begin with, please ask only one specific and practical question per post, so that it can get a single correct answer. You've asked two questions that may be answerable, and one general request for suggestions which we cannot answer firmly. Use the EDIT button to make your question better.

Comment: I am the original poster. Yes I am aware this is an old PC but as you might guess there are special reasons for keeping it going for a while longer. My question relates to cluster sizing and I would appreciate any technical input.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say in general the larger the cluster size, the less file system overhead. You give up on some file system features though, compression being an example.

Now the question is how much of an impact more or less file system overhead has. It will for example influence the size of the $Bitmap, but it will not influence size of the $MFT as in general it requires one entry per file regardless the cluster size and assuming a file isn't severely fragmented.

I'd recommend simply trying, perhaps a simple benchmark tool may be of help. Example: https://www.ghacks.net/2020/09/09/diskbench-is-a-freeware-tool-that-can-benchmark-your-hard-drive/.

One more thing that may help you: NTFS automatically updates the last access time and date stamp on folders and files when NTFS traverses its B-tree folder structure. To enhance NTFS performance you can disable this behavior and reduce NTFS's operational overhead without significantly impairing functionality.

In the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem Registry key, change the NtfsDisableLastAccessUpdate value of type REG_DWORD from the default value 0 (enabled) to 1 (disabled). This Registry value doesn't exist by default, so you need to enter it manually.